# Python argument parsing get wrong result

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have a python script to parse input argument from user .my code is like this

```
   def get_arg(argv):
    result = {}
    input_file=stag_db=main_tb=stag_table=main_table = "";
    debug="N"

    msg =  '''        Syntax: dt transaction date 
                      -i input_file (E.g. input_file.tar.gz) 
                      -ds staging_database
                      -dm main_database
                      -ts staging_table
                      -tm main_table
                      -db debug (Y/N)'''
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hd:i:ds:dm:db:ts:tm:",["ifile=","ofile="])
        print args
        print opts
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        f_end_process(msg)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            f_end_process(msg)   
        elif opt == "-i":
           input_file = arg
        elif opt == "-ds":
            stag_db = arg
        elif opt == "-dm":
            main_tb = arg
        elif opt == "-ts":
            stag_table = arg
        elif opt == "-tm":
            main_table = arg
        elif opt == "-db":
            debug = arg
    result = {'input_file':input_file,'stag_db':stag_db,'main_tb':main_tb,'stag_table':stag_table,'main_table':main_table}
    print result
    if '' in result.values():
        exit_status=-1
        f_end_process(msg)
    result['debug']= debug
    return  result

def main():
    global input_arg 
    input_arg = get_arg(sys.argv[1:])
    print "process started at " +strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  
    print input_arg
```

i am running code like this

```
python main.py -i ok.txt -ds ds_val -dm dm_val -ts tas_val -tm tm_val
```

i want to parse all input arguments to a list. i imported all required modules to my script

now i am able to parse only -i input.How can i parse -tm,-ts ,-dm,-ds iputs?

Comment: You're supposed to pass `sys.argv[1:]`, not `argv`. I don't know enough about `getopt` to tell if that's the whole problem.

Comment: i am passing like sys.argv[1:].

Comment: Can you show actual code that runs and demonstrates the problem when you run it?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the `argparse` module, which will do all this for you, and do it better?

Comment: @Paul Griffiths i am using python2.6

Comment: @user2602709: `optparse`, then.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage using `argparse`, in just a few lines.

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--input-file', '-i', type=str,
                        help='input file (eg: input_file.tar.gz)')
    parser.add_argument('--staging-db', '-S', type=str,
                        help='staging database name')
    parser.add_argument('--main-db', '-M', type=str,
                        help='main database name')
    parser.add_argument('--staging-table', '-s', type=str,
                        help='staging table name')
    parser.add_argument('--main-table', '-m', type=str,
                        help='main table name')
    parser.add_argument('--debug', '-d', type=bool, default=False,
                        help="activate debug mode (defaults to False)")
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

The parser help is generated by `argparse`. You can output it by typing

```
$ python YOURSCRIPT.py --help
```

Answer (score 1):

In an interactive Python experiment with passing various `argv` arrays to `getopt`

```
>>> getopt.getopt(['-hd','1'],"hd:i:ds:dm:db:ts:tm:")
([('-h', ''), ('-d', '1')], [])
```

You did not tell it to look for an `-hd` option, but rather a `-h` and a `-d` that takes an argument.

Generally for multiletter options, argument parsers expect you to use `--`.  Your getopt should be

```
>>> getopt.getopt(['--hd','1'],"i:",["hd=","ds=",...])
([('--hd', '1')], [])
```

But, do consider `argparse`.